# Cannot cancel ROS2 action goal immediately after sending

Tags: ros, ros2, action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some toy code to test ROS2 action cancelation. I'm trying to send an action goal, then cancel it immediately. With print statements, I can verify that the action goal is received, but the cancellation callback does not run. The program hangs when the cancellation is requested.

Send the action goal:

```
auto goal_handle = std::get<1>(client_tuple)->async_send_goal(stage_request.hybrid_request, send_goal_options);
```

^don't worry about the tuple here. It's unconventional but it works.

Now try to cancel it immediately afterwards:

```
// I've tried a sleep() here. No change
auto cancellation_future = std::get<1>(client_tuple)->async_cancel_all_goals();
```

I have also tried this method of cancellation:

```
            auto cancellation_future = std::get<1>(client_tuple)->async_cancel_goal(goal_handle.get());
            if (rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(m_node, cancellation_future) !=
                rclcpp::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS)
            {
                // This does not print:
                RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "FAILED TO CANCEL!");
            }
            // This does not print, it is stuck above this line:
            RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "CANCELED");
```

My action server is set up like so:

```
  hybrid_planning_request_server_ = rclcpp_action::create_server<moveit_msgs::action::HybridPlanner>(
      this->get_node_base_interface(), this->get_node_clock_interface(), this->get_node_logging_interface(),
      this->get_node_waitables_interface(), hybrid_planning_action_name,
      // Goal callback
      [](const rclcpp_action::GoalUUID& /*unused*/,
         std::shared_ptr<const moveit_msgs::action::HybridPlanner::Goal> /*unused*/) {
        // This does print
        RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Received goal request");
        return rclcpp_action::GoalResponse::ACCEPT_AND_EXECUTE;
      },
      // Cancel callback
      [this](std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ServerGoalHandle<moveit_msgs::action::HybridPlanner>> /*unused*/) {
        // This does not print:
        RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Received request to cancel global goal manager");
        return rclcpp_action::CancelResponse::ACCEPT;
      },
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400835/cannot-cancel-ros2-action-goal-immediately-after-sending/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2022-05-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2022-05-18**:
I wonder if I need to add another spinning thread? Or, somebody else tipped me off that the callbacks may be in the same group? I don't know what that means/how to fix it.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2022-05-18**:
I've tried a MultiThreadedExecutor now. Still no luck.

**Comment by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) on 2022-05-18**:
Can you post the full source code for your test files? Like you mentioned, the behavior of the executor and the callback groups are important here.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2022-05-18**:
I dropped some code in to verify the goal is accepted. This never prints, so it looks like the problem is the action server not responding:

```
if (rclcpp_action::GoalStatus::STATUS_ACCEPTED != future_goal_handle.get()->get_status())
{
    RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(LOGGER, "Goal was not accepted");
    return;
}
RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(LOGGER, "Goal was accepted!");
```

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2022-05-18**:
@jschornak code for the action server which is not responding is here:  https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/5a39a7f6ce84ce1ec17567ff5593ca9d376b21b6/moveit_ros/hybrid_planning/hybrid_planning_manager/hybrid_planning_manager_component/src/hybrid_planning_manager.cpp#L147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a solution in this PR:

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/pull/1272

A quick-and-dirty fix is to move long-running callbacks into a detached thread, like in this rclcpp demo: https://github.com/AndyZe/examples/blob/14c743af8bbca6a40e83da7a470c5332dce66d9d/rclcpp/actions/minimal_action_server/member_functions.cpp#L110

And also to make sure each action server (if you have several) has its own callback group.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1